# Read a single bit from a buffer of char

Tags: c, arrays, bitmask

I would to implement a function like this:

```
int read_single_bit(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int index)
```

where index is the offset of the bit that I would want to read.

How do I use bit shifting or masking to achieve this?

Comment: What is wrong with your implementation?

Comment: Good start to use unsigned integers. You also seem to know what you need. Now start writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buffer[index/8] & (1u<<(index%8))
```

should do it (that is, view `buffer` as a bit array and test the bit at `index`).

Similarly:

```
buffer[index/8] |= (1u<<(index%8))
```

should set the `index-th` bit.

Or you could store a table of the eight shift states of 1 and `&` against that

```
unsigned char bits[] = { 1u<<0, 1u<<1, 1u<<2, 1u<<3, 1u<<4, 1u<<5, 1u<<6, 1u<<7 };
```

If your compiler doesn't optimize those `/` and `%` to bit ops (more efficient), then:

```
 unsigned_int / 8  == unsigned_int >> 3
 unsigned_int % 8  == unsigned_int & 0x07  //0x07 == 0000 0111
```

so

```
 buffer[index>>3] & (1u<<(index&0x07u))  //test
 buffer[index>>3] |= (1u<<(index&0x07u)) //set
```

Comment: Shifting left is mod 8?

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, I don't think so. But are you aware why actually not? With minor other constraints you would have UB. You should write your code more safely. (Sorry, had to dummy-edit to remove the DV.

Comment: OP declared index as an `unsigned int` and `buffer` as an unsigned char array. There should be no issue with bit ops on unsigned integers.

Comment: Oh, you very well do signed arithmetics. It is a really well-meant hint to research where any why (that is very important knowledge, no nastyness).

Comment: @Olaf I think I know what you're hinting at. The `1` literal is a `signed int` and I would it UB if the bit from the left-shift hit the sign bit, but it doesn't because luckily I'm only shifting the lower 8 bits, but I still had better written `1u`, correct?

Comment: @PSkocik: Exactly. Sorry, but that is really important and many people ignore that. FYI: Using an `int` constant on the LHS of a bitshift triggered my first comment (and the DV), but some minutes later somehow it came into my mind you did not shift that far.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for pointing that out. It's actually useful info for some software of mine.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to split this into three separate tasks:

1. Determining which `char` contains the bit that you're looking for.
2. Determining the bit offset into that `char` that you need to read.
3. Actually selecting that bit out of that `char`.

I'll leave parts (1) and (2) as exercises, since they're not too bad. For part (3), one trick you might find useful would be to do a bitwise AND between the byte in question and a byte with a single `1` bit at the index that you want. For example, suppose you want to get the fourth bit out of a byte. You could then do something like this:

```
Byte:   11011100
Mask:   00001000
----------------
AND:    00001000
```

So think about the following: how would you generate the mask that you need given that you know the bit index? And how would you convert the AND result back to a single bit?

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting, you did write a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible implementation of your function might look like this:

```
int read_single_bit(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int index)
{
    unsigned char c = buffer[index / 8]; //getting the byte which contains the bit
    unsigned int bit_position = index % 8; //getting the position of that bit within the byte

    return ((c >> (7 - bit_position)) & 1);
    //shifting that byte to the right with (7 - bit_position) will move the bit whose value you want to know at "the end" of the byte.
    //then, by doing bitwise AND with the new byte and 1 (whose binary representation is 00000001) will yield 1 or 0, depending on the value of the bit you need.
}
```

Comment: Don't mix signed and unsigned without need and exactly knowing what you do.